# C++ Error Reporting Interface

Tags: c++

I'm designing an interface that can be used to report errors in C++. (I'm working with a legacy system where exceptions are out of question.) In my youthful naivety, I started along these lines while designing my API:

```
bool DoStuff(int amount, string* error);
```

Return value signals success/failure, while *error* is used to report a human readable explanation. So far so good. Subroutine calls passed along the *error* pointer and everything was hunky-dory.

I ran into the following problems with this design (so far):

1. Cannot report warnings.

   Not thread-safe.

Next, I decided to go with the following interface, instead of plain *string*:

```
class Issues {
 public:
  void Error(const string& message);
  void Warning(const string& message);
  void Merge(const Issues& issues);
}
```

So that I can change my API like this:

```
bool DoStuff(int amount, Issues* issues);
```

I'm wondering, is there a more generic/standard API out there that deals with this problem? If yes, I'd like to take a look.

**UPDATE**: I'm not looking for a logging library. For those who are curious, imagine you're writing a query engine that includes a compiler. The compiler issues warnings and errors, and those need to be returned to the user, as part of the response. Logging has its place in the design, but this is not it.

Comment: Why do you pass `issues` as a pointer, and not a reference, or even a value?

Comment: Well, if you pass it as a value then it gets destructed on return, losing all errors and warnings. Why not reference? The Google C++ style guide states that things you update should be passed in as pointers (references are reserved for read-only, that is, const arguments).

Comment: The Google C++ style guide is an abomination that none of us should have to follow. If you have specific requirements for supporting a specific legacy interface, those are the requirements. Else, we are in C++ and use all tools at our disposal. The Google Style Guide is especially terrible.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you'd like to use the error-reporting interface?

Answer (score 3):

I usually use things like `boost::signals` or .NET delegates to report errors/warning/logging/whatever. You report errors with no changes to the interface, and the library user plugs whatever she wants to the signal to get the error reports (writing to a file, updating a console window, aborting the program, throwing an exception, ignoring warnings, etc).

Something like this, at eg. global scope:

```
boost::signal<void(std::string const&)> logError;
boost::signal<void(std::string const&)> logWarning;
```

and then

```
void routineWhichMayFail()
{
    ...
    if (answer != 42)
    {
        logError("Universal error");
        return;
    }
}
```

and you connect something to `logError` and `logWarning` at initialization:

```
void robustErrorHandler(std::string const& msg)
{
    std::cerr << "Error: " << msg << "\n";
    std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void initializeMyProgram()
{
    logError.connect(&robustErrorHandler);
}
```

You can even throw exceptions in the error handler instead of exiting, and use fancier things than bare functions (logging classes, "delegates" -- pointers to methods with a `this` object bundled, RPC to a distant server). This way, you decouple the error *handling* from error *reporting*, which is good. You can also report to multiple destinations, you can even have your handlers return a boolean telling whether the action should be eg. retried.

Comment: Boost Signals2 is the thread safe version. See here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/signals2.html

Comment: @anand: If it is necessary, you can use `signals2`, yes.

Comment: How do I separate errors that result from serving different requests? You see, clients want errors that pertain to their request only ...

Comment: @Lajos: You did not mention this. However, the scheme is flexible.  I imagine there is some request ID stored in the object which contains `DoStuff`: you could either replace it / augment it with a `boost::signal` object instead of having a global one, or pass the ID to the global `logError` object and dispatch from there. Another possibility is to pass the `boost::signal` object around.

Comment: Yes. Since the OP mentioned that with his current solution he got the thread safety problem I mentioned about boost::signals2.

Answer (score 2):

From your explanation it sounds like you are trying to implement a logging library for your project. You can look at [log4cpp](http://log4cpp.sourceforge.net) or [Boost.Log](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: Updated my question: it's not a logging library I'm looking for.